# REST POST Request not working

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-data-services

Here is my WCF Rest Api which is using POST.

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Test/{id}")]
        void Test(string id);
```

I am calling this from my REST DHC Client, through the url

```
http://localhost/RestTestWebService.svc/json/Test/abs
```

Now I get the error **Method not allowed.**

What am I missing, also there is no information that I notice in logs.

Here is my web.config-

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>-->

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>




  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="RestTestWebServiceBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="RestTest.RestTestWebService" behaviorConfiguration="RestTestWebServiceBehaviors" >
        <endpoint name="json" address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehavior" contract="RestTest.IRestTestWebService"/>

        <!--<endpoint name="json" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RestTest.IRestTestWebService"/>-->
      </service>
    </services>




    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting your service on IIS. Please check if "Post" verb is allowed in your WebDav configuration

1. In IIS, select your website
2. Choose Handler Mapping
3. Select WebDAV from the list of Mappings
4. Click Request Restrictions
5. Then switch to the Verbs tab and highlight All Verbs
6. Restart the application in IIS.

If it still doesn't work, please try following ways.

- In IIS, disable your WebDav.

or

- Uninstall WebDav module.

  Server Manager -> Role -> Web Server -> Common HTTP Features -> WebDAV Publishing, and for client machine  Control Panel -> Uninstall Program -> Turn Windows features on or off -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP feautre -> WebDAV Publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Uri must specify the host number. 
Uri after the service name must be specified that described in uritemplate: `"...RestTestWebService.svc / Test / abs"`